# Working with large XML files in Postgresql

Tags: java, xml, postgresql, jdbc, libxml2

I am using Java JDBC to insert a rather large XML file (about 32MB) into an "xml" type column in Postgres using this particular approach / method:

```
public void setDataXML(PreparedStatement ps, Connection conn, int index, byte[] bytes) throws SQLException {
    SQLXML sqlxml = conn.createSQLXML();
    OutputStream os = sqlxml.setBinaryStream();
    try {
        os.write(bytes);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new SQLException(e);
    }
    ps.setSQLXML(index, sqlxml);
}
```

I am currently using the postgresql-9.4.1208.jar JDBC driver for this operation. Previously this was working just fine when running against a Postgres 9.0.4 database. I have since upgraded to a Postgres 9.4 database, and now this operation is failing with a:

```
    PreparedStatementCallback; SQL []; ERROR: invalid XML content
Detail: line 418061: internal error: Huge input lookup
nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid XML content
```

I have tested this on Windows as well as an Amazon Linux instance, and the results are the same. I know it has something to do with the size of the XML file, as severely reducing the sheer size of the XML file allows it to be inserted as desired.

What settings can I use on the driver / database, or how to configure as such to allow me to insert a large XML file with Postgres 9.4?

Comment: Do you need to take advantage of the PostgreSQL XML type or are you just storing it?  If you don't need to use the XML features then you could store it as a text type.

Comment: Ideally I would like to take advantage of the XML type so we can run xpath searches directly on the column as well as the validation that come with it. I understand we could go with a clob / text column as a last resort, but still don't understand what changed between Postgresql 9.0.4 and 9.4

Comment: I figured as much - I would take a look at the server logs to see if there is anything interesting there and, perhaps, update your JDBC driver to the newest.  Otherwise this sounds like a PostgreSQL bug in 9.4 that you may need to report.  9.5 is the current production release but that could be a good chunk of work just to try it.

Comment: It looks like this is a [limit in libxml2](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2012-August/msg00645.html) linked with your Postgres binary.

Comment: Just checked and it is the same situation for PosgreSQL 9.5 as well. So I am assuming there is no way to set the XML_PARSE_HUGE option that libxml2 requires to bypass this limitation directly through PostgreSQL? Then my only other option is to replace the libxml2 library that ships with PostgreSQL with a pathched version with this limitation turned off. That seems very short sighted by the PostgreSQL team unless I am missing something here

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue, but I have small and big xml files so it happens that sometimes the query just fail, and this is quite irritating. Are there any news about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this 'error' stems from the underlying xml library used to handle the XML parsing and processing (e.g. libxml/libxml2) and this kind of error can be found for a number of languages using the library - e.g. Python, [R](https://community.rstudio.com/t/xml-parser-internal-error-huge-input-lookup/70542), ... ([Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20140304155421.GM23803@rdorte.org))

The code does not show how Java is building the prepared statement, but, there is two ways of parsing XML in Postgres ([PostgresDoc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-xml.html)):

```
XMLPARSE (DOCUMENT '<?xml version="1.0"?><book><title>Manual</title><chpt>...</chpt></book>')
XMLPARSE (CONTENT 'abc<foo>bar</foo><bar>foo</bar>')
```

The second one is the default and might expect less data than the second one (also used when doing casting with `::` syntax like so `'<a>1</a>'::xml` ).

- Option 1: Explicitly construct your statement and explicitly use `XMLPARSE (DOCUMENT ...)`
- Option 2: Make the `DOCUMENT` the default with

  - `SET XML OPTION DOCUMENT;` or
  - `SET xmloption TO DOCUMENT;`